# user upload to my S3 bucket

Tags: python, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like for a user, **without** having to have an Amazon account, to be able to upload mutli-gigabyte files to an S3 bucket of mine.

How can I go about this? I want to enable a user to do this by giving them a key or perhaps through an upload form rather than making a bucket world-writeable obviously.

I'd prefer to use Python on my serverside, but the idea is that a user would need nothing more than their web browser or perhaps opening up their terminal and using built-in executables.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to proxy the file thorough your python backend to S3, that too large files. Instead you can configure S3 to accept files from user directly (without proxying through your backend code).

It is explained here: [Browser Uploads to S3 using HTML POST Forms](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434). This way your server need not handle any upload load at all.

If you also want your users to use their elsewhere ID (google/FB etc) to achieve this workflow, that too is possible. They will be able to upload these files to a sub-folder (path) in your bucket without exposing other parts of your bucket. This is detailed here: Web [Identity Federation with Mobile Applications](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313). Though it says mobile, you can apply the same to webapps.

Having said all that, as @Ratan points out, large file uploads could break in between when you try from a browser and it cant retry "only the failed parts". This is where a dedicated app's need come in. Another option is to ask your users to keep the files in their Dropbox/BOX.com account and your server can read from there - these services already take care of large file upload with all retries etc using their apps.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is relevant to .Net as language.

We had such requirement, where we had created an executable. The executable internally called a web method, which validated the app authenticated to upload files to AWS S3 or NOT.

You can do this using a web browser too, but I would not suggest this, if you are targeting big files.